# Simulate yield behavior of an entire python script in bash

Tags: python, bash

I know I can write

```
def counter():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

x = counter()
next(x) # 0
next(x) # 1
next(x) # 2
```

Suppose that I want to simulate this kind of behavior in a bash script. E.g. I want to have:

```
python3 counter.py "init"
i=$(python3 counter.py) # 0
i=$(python3 counter.py) # 1
i=$(python3 counter.py) # 2
```

Is it possible to have this kind of behavior, where the state of the python script is maintained between calls? My first guess would be to use a file intermediary but I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it.

Comment: If you want multiple calls to interact with state then you need some external mechanism for that. You could use a file. You could use an open file handle. You could use a named pipe/fifo/etc. But you need some known external location to keep the state.

Comment: You could also, of course, just write that function in sh/bash and use a global variable to keep the counter state so subsequent calls count appropriately.

Comment: @Kasra Isn't that the wrong direction? The OP seems to be asking for stateful functions/scripts in the shell not pipelines in python.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah it seems so!